# Simple question on predense set in a boolean algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Let B a complete boolean algebra and D a subsets of B. Then D is predense below $ b\in B $, i.e.  the downward closure of D  is dense below b, iff $b\le \bigvee D$.Proving this equivalence seemed like it would be an easy exercise, but I think I'm missing something. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Is it correct to say that if $q\le p$ is NOT true,  then $\neg p\le q $ ?

Comment: No: consider the power set algebra $\wp(X)$. You can have $A\nsubseteq B$ without having $X\setminus B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- If $b\not\le\bigvee D$, let $x=b\land\left(\neg\bigvee D\right)$, and use $x$ to show that $D$ is not predense below $b$.
- Show that if $D$ is not predense below $b$, there is an $x\le b$ such that $x\land d=0$ for all $d\in D$, and deduce that $b\not\le\bigvee D$.

You may find it helpful to start by proving the special case $b=1$: $D$ is predense in $B$ iff $\bigvee D=1$. It uses the same ideas, but with slightly less clutter.